# Ghostscript: preserve annotations (keep print/non-print distinction)?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm currently using GS to convert PDFs into PDFs (mostly to convert T1 fonts to CFF).

-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dAutoRotatePages=/Nones -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dPrinted=false

These are my flags that I use right now. Because I set dPrinted=false, it preserves the links in my files, even when they are set not to print.

But if I have links and annotations which normally would only show in one medium (on screen), dPrinted seems to force me to choose one way or the other for my converted file. Is there any way to input a PDF which has annotations on screen but not on paper, and output a PDF which has the same distinction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no, there is no way to keep **both** printing and non-printing annotations, you can have one or the other.

By altering Printed you can keep either printing annotations (Printed=true) or non-printed (Printed=false) annotations.

The distinction isn't down to the creation of the output PDF file, but the PDF interpreter, which can only behave, at the moment, as either a screen device or a printer. So it only processes one set of annotations.